# How can I parse json in python?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file called say `Student_DB.json`. It contains all infos related to a student in JSON format. So this is the structure:

```
{
    "students" : [
         { "id": "1", "satisfactory": "true", "entered_class": "8:30 AM", "left_class": "9:50 AM" },
         { "id": 2, ...},
         { "id": 3, ...}
    ]
}
```

I want to extract all different fields and check for each property i.e make an array of entered_class time for all students and aggregate them. How can I achieve this in python, please help.

Comment: I updated my post. Now this is JSON.

Comment: My downvote was because what you posted was obviously not JSON, and because the question displays a clear lack of research. It doesn't look like you even [googled `python json`](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+json).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your json file like:

```
{
    "students" : [
         { "id": 1, "satisfactory": True, "entered_class": "8:30 AM", "left_class": "9:50 AM" },
         { "id": 2, ...},
         { "id": 3, ...}
    ]
}
```

Extract data from json file:

```
with open('Student_DB.json') as f:
    contents = json.load(f)

for data in contents['students']:
    print(data)
    print(data['id'])
    print(data['entered_class'])
```

O/P:

```
{'id': 1, 'satisfactory': True, 'entered_class': '8:30 AM', 'left_class': '9:50 AM'}
1
8:30 AM
```

Comment: this just prints all the students. I need all student entered_class / any sub value in an array.

Comment: Thanks I got all the rows. and I can save it to arrays.